# Find the value of f(T) for big value T

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I am trying to solve a problem which is described below,

Given value of f(0) and k , which are  integers.

I need to find value of  f( T ). where  T<=10<sup>10</sup>

Recursive function is,

```
 f(n) =  2*f(n-1)              ,  if  4*f(n-1) <=k 
         k - ( 2*f(n-1) )      ,  if 4*f(n-1) > k
```

My efforts,

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


int main(){

     long k,f0,i;
     cin>>k>>f0;
     long operation ; 
     cin>>operation;
     long answer=f0;
     for(i=1;i<=operation;i++){
         answer=(4*answer <= k )?(2*answer):(k-(2*answer));
     }
     cout<<answer;
     return 0;

}
```

My code gives me right answer. But, The code will run 10<sup>10</sup> time in worst case that gives me Time Limit Exceed. I need more efficient solution for this problem. Please help me. I don't know the correct algorithm.

Comment: hmm I feel like there is a neat mathematical solution... would be nice to see this also posted in math stack exchange.

Comment: I think there's a neat mathematical solution if f(0) is between 0 and k/2. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 2f(0) < k then you can compute this function in O(log n) time (using exponentiation by squaring modulo k).

```
r = f(0) * 2^n mod k
return 2 * r >= k ? k - r : r
```

You can prove this by induction. The induction hypothesis is that 0 <= f(n) < k/2, and that the above code fragment computes f(n).

Here's a Python program which checks random test cases, comparing a naive implementation (`f`) with an optimized one (`g`).

```
def f(n, k, z):
    r = z
    for _ in xrange(n):
        if 4*r <= k:
            r = 2 * r
        else:
            r = k - 2 * r
    return r

def g(n, k, z):
    r = (z * pow(2, n, k)) % k
    if 2 * r >= k:
        r = k - r
    return r

import random

errs = 0
while errs < 20:
    k = random.randrange(100, 10000000)
    n = random.randrange(100000)
    z = random.randrange(k//2)
    a1 = f(n, k, z)
    a2 = g(n, k, z)
    if a1 != a2:
        print n, k, z, a1, a2
        errs += 1
    print '.',
```

Comment: TThank you sir @Paul Hankin

Answer (score 0):

Can you use methmetical solution before progamming and compulating?

Actually,
f(n) = f0*2^(n-1)            , if f(n-1)*4 <= k
       k - f0*2^(n-1)        , if f(n-1)*4 > k

thus, your code will write like this:

`condition = f0*pow(2, operation-2)
answer =  condition*4 =< k? condition*2: k - condition*2`

Comment: Good idea, but incorrect. If the algorithm wouldn't change strategies at every step depending on the size of the current value, one could compress `2*` into `2^`; but it does. For example, using `k=19` and `x0=2`, OP's `x6=5`, but yours is `-12`, if I haven't made a mistake.

Comment: @Amadan Yes your opinion is right, it seems finding out the critical n value reaching k is necessary, and this is the core time questioner wants to save.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple loop, your answer looks pretty tight; one could optimise a little bit using `answer<<2` instead of `4*answer`, and `answer<<1` for `2*answer`, but quite possibly your compiler is already doing that. If you're blowing the time with this, it might be necessary to reduce the loop itself somehow.

I can't figure out a mathematical pattern that @Shannon was going for, but I'm thinking we could exploit the fact that this function will sooner or later cycle. If the cycle is short enough, then we could short the loop by just getting the answer at the same point in the cycle.

So let's get some cycle detection equipment in the form of [Brent's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Brent's_algorithm), and see if we can cut the loop to reasonable levels.

```
def brent(f, x0):
    # main phase: search successive powers of two
    power = lam = 1
    tortoise = x0
    hare = f(x0)  # f(x0) is the element/node next to x0.
    while tortoise != hare:
        if power == lam:  # time to start a new power of two?
            tortoise = hare
            power *= 2
            lam = 0
        hare = f(hare)
        lam += 1

    # Find the position of the first repetition of length λ
    mu = 0
    tortoise = hare = x0
    for i in range(lam):
    # range(lam) produces a list with the values 0, 1, ... , lam-1
        hare = f(hare)
    # The distance between the hare and tortoise is now λ.

    # Next, the hare and tortoise move at same speed until they agree
    while tortoise != hare:
        tortoise = f(tortoise)
        hare = f(hare)
        mu += 1

    return lam, mu



f0 = 2
k = 198779
t = 10000000000

def f(x):
    if 4 * x <= k:
        return 2 * x
    else:
        return k - 2 * x

lam, mu = brent(f, f0)

t2 = t
if t >= mu + lam:              # if T is past the cycle's first loop,
    t2 = (t - mu) % lam + mu    # find the equivalent place in the first loop

x = f0
for i in range(t2):
    x = f(x)

print("Cycle start: %d; length: %d" % (mu, lam))
print("Equivalent result at index: %d" % t2)
print("Loop iterations skipped: %d" % (t - t2))
print("Result: %d" % x)
```

As opposed to the other proposed answers, this approach actually could use a memo array to speed up the process, since the start of the function is actually calculated multiple times (in particular, inside `brent`), or it may be irrelevant, depending on how big the cycle happens to be.

Comment: I think cycle detection is a viable approach -- assuming a short period, anyhow -- but I'm not sure you're using the right `f`.  I can't seem to match your answers using either my brute force code or my equivalent cycle code, so I don't think I'm missing some subtlety.

Comment: @DSM: Hmm... My `f` is not the original `f`. I should have said `def f2(prev_result)`, where `prev_result` is `f(n - 1)`. To check, with `k=19` and `f0=2`, my series is `2, 4, 8, 3, 6, 7, 5, 9, 1, 2, 4...`, do you get something different?

Comment: thanks amadan . your work is nice. but it still gives me TLE.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you proposed already has O(n).
To come up with more efficient algorithms, there is not that much direction we can go about. Some typical options we have

1.Decease the coefficients of the linear term( but I doubt it would make a difference in this case

2.Change to O(Logn)(typically use some sort of divide and conquer technique)

3.Change to O(1)

In this case, we can do the last one.
The recursion function is a piece-wise function

```
f(n) =  2*f(n-1)              ,  if  4*f(n-1) <=k
        k - ( 2*f(n-1) )      ,  if 4*f(n-1) > k
```

Let's tackle it by case:

case 1: if 4*f(n-1) <= k (1)(assuming the starting index is zero)
this is a obvious a geometry series

> a_n = 2*a_n-1

Therefore, have the formula

> Sn = 2^(n-1)*f(0) ----(*)

Case 2: if 4*f(n-1) > k (2), we have

> a_n = -2a_n-1 + k
>
> Assuming, a_j is the element in the sequence which just satisfy condition (2)

Nestedly sub in an_1 to the formula, you will obtain the equation

> an = k -2k +4k -8k... +(-2)^(n-j)* a_j
>
> k -2k 4k -8... is another gemo series
>
> Sn = k*(1-2^(n-j))/(1-2) ---gemo series sum formula with starting value k and ratio = -2

Therefore, we have a formula for an in the case 2

> an = k * (1-2^(n-j))/(1-2) + (-2)^(n-j) * a_j ----（**）

All we left to do it to find aj which just dissatisfy condition (1) and satisfy (2)

This can be obtained in constant time again using the formula we have for case 1:

> find n such that, 4*an = 4*Sn = 4*2^(n-1)*f(0) 
>   solve for n: 4*2^(n-1)*f(0) = k, if n is not integer, take ceiling of n

In my first attempt to solve this question, I had wrong assumption that the value of the sequence is monotonically increasing but in fact the sequence might jump between case 1 and case 2. Therefore, there might not be constant algorithm to solve the problem.

However, we can use utilize the result above to skip iterative update complexity.

The overall algorithm will look something like:

> start with T, K, and f(0)
>
> compute n that make the condition switch using either (*) or (**)
>
> > update f(0) with f(n), update T - n
>
> repeat
>
> > terminate when T-n = 0(the last iteration might over compute causing T-n<0, therefore, you need to go back a little bit if that happen)

Answer (score -2):

Create a map that can store your results. Before finding f(n) check in that map, if solution is already existed or not.
If exists, use that solution.
Otherwise find it, store it for future use.

For C++:

> Definition:

```
map<long,long>result;
```

> Insertion:

```
result[key]=value
```

> Accessing:

```
value=result[key];
```

> Checking:

```
map<long,long>::iterator it=result.find(key);
if(it==result.end())
{
    //key was not found, find the solution and insert into result
}
else
{
    return result[key];
}
```

Use above technique for better solution.

Comment: Same reason I downvoted @mirmdasif, it does not offer a solution OP can use. (Your answer is almost identical to his, and not usable for the same reasons.)